# How do I create an Eclipse project using the Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

How can I get the same result from Eclipse as I would from the console with `gradle init --type java-application --test-framework testng --dsl kotlin`?

I'm seeing the wizard:

[image: wizard1]

but no gradle-kotlin-dsl option:

[image: wizard2]

I'm [new](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/e5d08efaadad040346e589c46d9f84dbd462f510341c18ab3494f998@%3Cusers.netbeans.apache.org%3E) to Eclipse, but have both Gradle and Kotlin plugins installed.  However, I [now](https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-build-logic-from-groovy-to-kotlin/) see that's of little utility:

> Kotlin DSL is fully supported in Intellij IDEA and Android Studio.
>   Other IDEs, such as Eclipse or NetBeans, do not yet provide helpful
>   tools for editing Gradle Kotlin DSL files, however, importing and
>   working with Kotlin DSL-based builds work as usual.

Given that Eclipse doesn't fully support the Kotlin DSL, as I'd hoped, I'll probably try IDEA for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Gradle Kotlin** DSL does **not** seem **currently supported**.

See [Buildship issue #222 comment by Donát Csikós](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/222#issuecomment-539439944):

> Not really. The existing Kotlin integration in Eclipse is simply too
>   unstable to work with Gradle DSL. We'll coordinate with JetBrains how
>   can we improve the situation. I'll close this issue for the time being
>   and reopen when we have an update.